# select multiple facets with blacklight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, ruby-on-rails-plugins, blacklight

I am trying to implement a selection of multiple facets of the same category, so when the user selects option A1 and option A2 of category A and option B1 of category B - the results he should get are for (A1 **OR** A2) AND (B1).
I am working with solr and blacklight (v5.3.0).
I tried to use blacklight_advanced_search (v5.1.2) gem and changed the view for the advanced. I succeed to implement the view for that, but still the results that solr returns are A1 **AND** A2 AND B1.

How can I make solr use **OR** between the facets of the same category instead of AND?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Solr 5.4.0; Ruby:2.2.4; Rails:4.2.6**
here category A=color and B=productBrand
check how your filter query fq
For me, initial

> fq = [{"!term f=color}Blue","{!term f=color}Black","{!term
>   f=productBrand}Apple"]

But after refering Blacklight examples from https://github.com/sul-dlss/revs
their filter query also looks similar

> "fq"=>["((*:* -visibility_isi:[* TO *]) OR visibility_isi:1)", "{!raw
>   f=format_ssim}black-and-white negatives", "{!raw f=marque_ssim}Ford",
>   "{!raw f=marque_ssim}Chevy"] which is working

but its not working for me , and  blacklight_advanced_search --version problem

So, i changed the **request.rb** file -- change action ***append_filter_query*** according to the requirements
Also edit catalog.rb

> **config.add_facet_field 'productBrand', label: 'Brand' ,  :tag =>
>   'some-tag', :ex => 'some-tag'**
>
> **config.add_facet_field 'color', label: 'Color' ,  :tag => 'color', :ex => 'color'**

After editing the files i got this fq which is working as i want it to be
(similar to ur requirement) selects Blue or Black and Apple

> **fq=["{!tag=color}color:(Blue Black)",
>   "{!tag=some-tag}productBrand:(Apple)]**

Might not be the good way to edit request.rb but couldn't able to find out the alternative way

see request.rb in ***\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\blacklight-6.0.2\lib\blacklight\solr***

ref:**http://yonik.com/multi-select-faceting/**

Example CODE:

```
def append_filter_query(query)
    #$facet_value=query
    unless query.nil?
    $r= /.*}(.*)/.match(query)[1]
    $l=/^({.*})/.match(query)[1]
        if self['fq'].empty?
            ampati()
        else
            $flag_new=false
            self['fq'].each{|item| 
            $s=/.*}(.*\w)*:/.match(item)[1]
            unless $l.include? $s
                #$s=color
                $flag_new=true
            else
                $flag_new=false
            end
            }

            if $flag_new
                ampati()
            else
                self['fq'].map!{|item|
                $fac=/.*}(.*\w)*:/.match(item)[1]
                if $l.include? $fac
                    item=/(.*\w)/.match(item)[1]<<" "<<$r<<")"
                else
                    item
                end

                }
            end
        end
    end

  end


  def ampati()
    if $l.include? "color"
        $c="{!tag=color}color:("<<$r<<")"
        self['fq']<<$c
    end
    if $l.include? "productBrand"
        $e="{!tag=some-tag}productBrand:("<<$r<<")"
        self['fq']<<$e
    end
  end
```

Comment: thank you for posting an answer. Please consider editing your post to use back-ticks for inline code formatting